# Fresh git clone showing changed files

Tags: git, github, openfoam

I am doing a clone of a git repository and I am finding changed files. I have looked at some of the other posts with similar issues, but as of yet the steps don't seem to help. I have tried adjusting the autocrlf settings, the case settings and some of the other configurations, but I am still seeing modified files, when I do 'git status'.

The configurations from the core section of the .git/config is:

```
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = true
bare = false
logallrefupdates = true
ignorecase = false
precomposeunicode = true
autocrlf = false
```

A truncated sample of paths that are being shown as modified are:

```
modified:   applications/test/Dictionary/Make/files
modified:   applications/test/Dictionary/Make/options
modified:   applications/test/Dictionary/Test-Dictionary.C
modified:   src/OpenFOAM/interpolations/patchToPatchInterpolation/PatchToPatchInterpolation.H
modified:   src/OpenFOAM/interpolations/primitivePatchInterpolation/PrimitivePatchInterpolation.H
modified:   src/OpenFOAM/matrices/LduMatrix/LduMatrix/LduMatrix.C
modified:   src/OpenFOAM/matrices/LduMatrix/LduMatrix/LduMatrix.H
modified:   src/OpenFOAM/matrices/LduMatrix/LduMatrix/LduMatrixATmul.C
modified:   src/OpenFOAM/matrices/LduMatrix/LduMatrix/LduMatrixOperations.C
```

A truncated sample of paths that are being shown as untracked are:

```
applications/test/Dictionary/Test-dictionary.C
applications/test/Dictionary/testDict
applications/test/Dictionary/testDict2
applications/test/Dictionary/testDictInc
applications/test/Dictionary/testDictRegex
applications/test/Dictionary/value
src/OpenFOAM/matrices/LduMatrix/LduMatrix/lduMatrix.C
src/OpenFOAM/matrices/LduMatrix/LduMatrix/lduMatrix.H
src/OpenFOAM/matrices/LduMatrix/LduMatrix/lduMatrixATmul.C
src/OpenFOAM/matrices/LduMatrix/LduMatrix/lduMatrixOperations.C
src/OpenFOAM/matrices/LduMatrix/LduMatrix/lduMatrixPreconditioner.C
src/OpenFOAM/matrices/LduMatrix/LduMatrix/lduMatrixSmoother.C
src/OpenFOAM/matrices/LduMatrix/LduMatrix/lduMatrixSolver.C
src/OpenFOAM/matrices/LduMatrix/LduMatrix/lduMatrixTemplates.C
src/OpenFOAM/matrices/LduMatrix/LduMatrix/lduMatrixUpdateMatrixInterfaces.C
```

I did the following after each config change:

```
rm -rf *
git reset --hard 
git status
```

The Git repository is git://github.com/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.x.git and the current operating system is MacOS X 10.9.5. Git version is 1.9.3. File system is HFS+ (case-insensitive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there are files in the repository that exist in both uppercase and lowercase form, in the same directory. For example 'dictionary' and 'Dictionary'. The solution on the MacOS X side is to create a case-sensitive HFS+ disk image, mount that and then checkout the repository in the mounted path.

Command used:

```
hdiutil create -size 1g -fs "Case-sensitive Journaled HFS+" -volname "OpenFOAM Development" openfoam-development.dmg
```

It would have probably been better to avoid the issue causing the problem, but I just need to accept this limitation.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a diff do you see any actual changes? I've seen this before when I've cloned a repository that had UNIX line endings and I was on Windows, so it automatically converted them to Windows.

Comment: I do see changes. I have selected 'ignore whitespace' in the diff tool, but still see changes. I am stumped. Don't have this issues with other repositories. I have even tried a fresh clone, just to be sure. I am tempted to test on a Linux VM, but would rather avoid spending the time creating, if I can.

Comment: I tried a clone and received the same issue from Windows. I've never seen that happen before.

Comment: I was able to track something down, I'm on Windows 8 and noticed there are 2 files missing in the changes. JohnsonJacksonParticleThetaFvPatchScalarField.C and JohnsonJacksonParticleThetaFvPatchScalarField.H when I tried to manually created these files I wasn't able to because windows wouldn't let me type past JohnsonJacksonParticleThetaFvPatchScalarField so there seems to be a file name limit.

Comment: It seems Windows has a 260 file path limit, and since these files are nested very deeply git is running  into an issue and isn't able to setup those files properly so that's why we're seeing changes since we don't have the latest.